# Uploading Image using ChromeDriver on Android

Tags: java, android, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to upload a image in Android using ChromeDriver.
so at first, i used sendKeys(IMG_PATH_ON_PC); to input but it wasn't worked.
console says

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED

and then i tried to upload it from my device.
i pushed an image via adb to /sdcard/imgtoupload.png
and used sendKeys('/sdcard/imgtoupload.png'); but it doesn't work either.
ChromeDriver says it's not an Absolute Path.

what do i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

use //mnt/sdcard instead of /sdcard